# XSLT 1.0 Function to remove a delimiter from a string

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to create a reusable XSLT 1.0 function to remove a delimiter from any given string. Since I am working in a 3rd party application, the source XML and the compiler are black-box to me. The code I have produces good results if I use:
`<xsl:value-of select="translate(variable,$delimiter,'')"/>` for each string I want to sanitize, but if I try to use the function I wrote below by calling `<xsl:value-of select="ecm:rmdelim(variable)"/>` the results truncate at that point. What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:ecm="http://tempuri.org/mynamespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ecm"
    extension-element-prefixes="func"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <!-- set the delimiter -->
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'^'"/>
  <!-- create function to remove delimiters from a string -->
  <func:function name="ecm:rmdelim">
      <xsl:param name="arg"/>
      <func:result select="translate($arg,$delimiter,'')"/>
  </func:function>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own functions only if your processor supports the EXSLT `func:function` extension  element. Very few processors do. You can find out if your does by looking at the result of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="element-available('func:function')"/>
```

> Since I am working in a 3rd party application, the source XML and the compiler are black-box to me.

You can see what the source XML looks like by applying the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) to it.

And you can identify the processor by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I got answers of 'False' and 'Microsoft' respectively. At least now I know to stop banging my head against this. It also led me to ```<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />``` to verify my version, so I have a lot more information about the environment I am working within, which I appreciate.

Comment: Note that `system-property('xsl:version')` returns the version of XSLT that the processor supports, not the version of the processor itself. In case of Microsoft, it will be always `1.0`. OTOH, there may be other extension mechanisms available - see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986124.aspx